# -[CFString intValue]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xa3a2610

Tags: ios6.1

I find some same topic in stackoverflow, but i can't solve my problems.

This is my code

In my .h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *favoriteShops;
```

My .m

```
NSString *idStr = @"";
NSString *shopTypeId = @"";
for (SHDFavoriteShopView *favoriteShopView in favoriteShops) {
            idStr = [favoriteShopView valueForKey:kId];
            shopTypeId = [favoriteShopView valueForKey:kShopTypeId];
            if (tappedView.tag == [idStr intValue]) {  // Crash here
                shop.shopType = [shopTypeId intValue];
                break;
            }

        }
```

I have problem sometime, not usually.

Could you please help me.

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an indication that the string you are accessing (`idString` in this case) has already been freed. There are a number of reasons why this can happen. If the string was originally allocated via an auto-released method (such as `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"..."]`), and the string got auto-released. Or if you allocated the string, but later released it by explicitly calling `[idStr release]`. You need to make sure that you are not re-using a string after it's already been released. That can be tricky!

Comment: i use [idStr release] after the loop. But i have problem in the loop

Comment: You shouldn't be releasing `idStr` after the loop! It's value changes on every iteration of the loop, so what are you releasing? Just the last value! But that's not the problem you're seeing here. I'd look in `favoriteShopView`. You're asking `favoriteShopView` for the value of some key, and it's returning the string pointed to by `idStr`. So it may be an already deallocated string by that point. If you post the code for `SDHFavoriteShopView`, that might help narrow it down.

Comment: favoriteShopView  is NSDictionary . This's my mistake. But when i replace SHDFavoriteShopView by NSDictionary, i have the same problem

Comment: when i use [[favoriteShopView valueForKey:kId] intValue], and [[favoriteShopView valueForKey:kShopTypeId] intValue], i have no problem